# Existence of fully supported element in a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (and in finite abelian groups)

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, coding-theory, abelian-groups

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z} / (p)$, the field of $p$ elements, $p$ a prime,  with $\{v_1, \dotsc, v_n \}$ a basis for $V$. An element $x \in V$ is called "fully supported" if $x = \sum_{i =1}^n c_i v_i$ with $0 \neq c_i \in \mathbb{F}$ for all $i$. Let $V_i$ be the subspace generated by $v_i$.

Let $U \leq V$ be a subspace of $V$. For $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $U_i$ be the set of $z_i \in V_i$ such that $z_1 + \dotsc + z_i + \dotsc + z_n \in U$ for some $z_j \in V_j$, $j \neq i$. Clearly $U_i$ is a subspace of $V$.

Question A: Assume $U_i = V_i$ for all $i$. Under what circumstances does there exist (or does there not exist) a fully supported element in $U$?

There are many occasions when the existence of such element in $U$ are guaranteed. For instance when $n = 2$ or when $\dim(U) = 1$. But I'd like to point out two instances when they don't exist in $U$. For instance when $n = 3$ and $p = 2$, set $U$ to be the subspace generated by $v_1 + v_2$ and $v_2 + v_3$. Another instance is when $n \gg p^m $ where $m = \dim(U)$, an example can be easily constructed such that fully supported elements don't exist in $U$.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can point me to the existing results (if any) or related research work on this topic. Question A can be generalized to any finite abelian $p$-group:

Question B: Let $X = \prod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ be a finite abelian $p$-group where $X_i = \langle x_i \rangle $, $\lvert x_i\rvert = p^{h_i}$, $h_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $Y \leq X$. Define $Y_i$ the same way as $U_i$ was defined before. It is easy to see that $Y_i$ is a subgroup of $X_i$. Assume $Y_i = X_i$ for all $i$. Under what conditions is a fully supported element guaranteed to exist or not exist in $Y$? Here a fully supported element in $X$ is of the form $(x_1^{a_1}, \dotsc, x_n^{a_n})$ where $ 0 < a_i < p^{h_i}$, $(a_i, p) = 1$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: The word "primitive" usually means some kind of "initial" feature. It sounds strange for the use here (fully supported elements). The condition in QA is that $U$ is fully supported (so QA is "when does a fully supported subspace contain a fully supported element?")

Comment: The hypothesis that $U$ is fully supported, i.e. for each $i$ there exists $u \in U$ with $u_i \not= 0$, is satisfied by any interesting $p$-ary code $U$. (Since if it fails the code isn't making any use of position $i$.) Maybe there are results from coding theory on when a code contains a fully supported element? For instance if $p=2$ then the only fully supported element is $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$. This is in a cyclic code of odd length $n$ if and only if the generator polynomial does not have $1$ as a root.

Comment: I also felt the name "primitive" wasn't best but couldn't think of a better one. Thank you for your suggestion; I have modified the post accordingly.