# Existence of full-weight codeword in a linear q-ary code

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, enumerative-combinatorics, coding-theory

I'm new to coding theory but would like to ask the following question:

Let $C$ be a linear $q$-ary code over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of length $n$ and dimension $k$ where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field with $q$ elements. Assume $C$ is fully supported in each position, that is for each position, every element in $\mathbb{F}_q$ appears in some codeword of $C$ at that position.

Question: under what conditions with respect to $(n,k,q)$ is  a full-weight codeword (that is with nonzero entries in every position) in $C$ guaranteed to exist or not exist?

There seems to be answers to the question in several situations:

1. If $q = 2$ the question seems to be well understood.
2. There is at least partial answer for the so-called general MDS-codes. For instance see Theorem 3 in the following article:
   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.05634.pdf
3. Any result on the so-called full-weight spectrum codes or maximum weight spectrum codes certainly addresses this question. For instance see another article of Alderson:
   https://toc.ui.ac.ir/article_23512_5d71778dc799071faf41dab6222a7662.pdf

But I wonder if there are more general results directly targeting the above question. In a way this question stems from another recent post of mine. Instead of updating that post,  allow me to reformulate the question in a more coding theoretic language hoping that the experts in this field can share some insights.
[Existence of fully supported element in a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (and in finite abelian groups)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438560/existence-of-fully-supported-element-in-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-over?noredirect=1#comment1130891_438560)